# Session flash in redirect is not working

Tags: session, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have this code in my controller

```
public function deleteDependent(Request $request)
{
HMO::deleteDependent($request); 

if(session()->has('hmo_id'))
{
    session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
    return redirect()->route('edit-user', request('hmo_id'));  
}
else
{
    return redirect()->route('edit', request('hmo_id'));  
}
```

}

And also this is my code in view

```
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-1">

            @if(session()->has('status'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">
             <strong>Success!</strong>  your request is waiting for Admin approval.
            </div>
            @endif
        </div>
```

Redirect is working properly but the session flash is not read by the view,
what am I missing ?

Comment: i think its `session()->flash()->('success', 'Message);` you are setting as `status` but looking for `success`

Comment: I already fix that issue, but still not working.

Comment: can you `dd(session()->get('hmo_id));` and see what you get?

Comment: @usrNotFound it shows 1 , its has a value.

Comment: It works now thanks man @usrNotFound its just a cache issue.